# Raspberry Pi used as a cheap serial-to-WLAN converter

Tags: serial

I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a serial-to-TCP converter. The Raspberry Pi should be a TCP-server that accept one TCP client (because more connections would end in a complete mess on the serial port!).

I want to connect to the Raspberry Pi from a computer that reads out data from a device that is connected to the Raspberry Pi with a serial converter. The serial converter already works, and I've also set up a WLAN access point.

Are there built-in tools in [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) that help me doing this? I don't want that the Raspberry Pi connects to another computer and redirects the serial port to a port on the computer. I want the Raspberry Pi to act as a server where clients can connect to the port and talk to the device that is connected to the serial port.

Comment: The ser2net application can do this. It's probably in Debian.

Comment: socat also could be used, and do not forget about ppp package.

Comment: I have a similar project which uses Python to parse then forward the message here: https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2021/11/04/raspberry-pi-rs232-marine-compass-protocol-converter-in-python Advantage being you can parse / revalidate etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For basic network communication `nc` or netcat, as suggested by [*joan*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24163/613), is sufficient. However, if you for example want to forward a serial console or encrypt the connection `socat` is probably more convenient. For inspiration  here are two working examples of the mentioned applications.

#### Serial console via TCP

To connect directly to the serial port with socat the following command can be used:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1d /dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,echo=0,raw
```

The escape char is set to <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>.

This can be expanded into a tcp-server like this:

```
socat tcp-listen:54321,reuseaddr /dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,raw,echo=0
```

This will allow only one client to connect, as per the OPs request. Wrap it with a while-loop to keep the server going between reconnects:

```
while true; do
  socat tcp-listen:54321,reuseaddr /dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,raw,echo=0
done
```

Now you can connect to the serial port through the tcp-server like this:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1d tcp:server-host:54321
```

### Serial console via SSL

To encrypt the connection, you first need to generate two key-pairs, see [*Example for openssl connection using socat*](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssl.txt) for the details, here is a summary:

```
# Generate self signed server certificate
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -x509 -days 3653 -out server.crt
cat server.key server.crt > server.pem
chmod 600 server.key server.pem

# Generate self signed client certificate
openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client.key -x509 -days 3653 -out client.crt
cat client.key client.crt > client.pem
chmod 600 client.key client.pem
```

Copy the pem-files to their respective hosts, do the opposite with the crt-files, e.g.:

```
scp server.pem client.crt server-host:
scp client.pem server.crt client-host:
```

Now the server can be run like this:

```
socat openssl-listen:1443,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt /dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,echo=0,raw
```

Connect to the serial console like this:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1d openssl:server-host:1443,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible with netcat. What you do is you have netcat listen to a port that you choose, and have it write to, and take input from, the serial port. The command itself will be something similar to

```
nc -l $PORT < /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: The trick will be getting this to know when to give up on an open (but abandoned) connection and loop back to run again and potentially accept a new connection.  Otherwise various client/network failures can leave it stuck for days.  Netcat does have a timeout option.  Also something like stty will need to configure the port.

Answer (score 1):

The netcat package may do what you want.

You should be able to redirect the serial link to and from a network address.