# send data from a virtual serial port to a tcp server

Tags: serial

I want to send data from my PI (that doesn't have a serial port) to a serial device.

now for this I understadn I need to create a virtual port on the pi and send the data from it

in windows I use VSPE software , that create my the virtual port and make the connection to the TcoToSerail tcp server (Moxa).

what I have so far is a connection to the TcpServer(the PI is a TCP client ) :
from this post :

[Raspberry Pi used as a cheap serial-to-WLAN converter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/raspberry-pi-used-as-a-cheap-serial-to-wlan-converter)

I use this line only :

```
socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1d tcp:MYServerIP:12345
```

and I can se there is a connection (the tcp server show me that my PI is connected )

my question now is :

how do I send to it data?
I want to send to the server this message:

"0x02 0x30 0x31 0x03 0x38 0x39"

Thanks ,

**** if someone have another solution \ way to do this - I will accept any help

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - and based on misconception - all Pi have a serial port

Comment: I'm not using the serial port ..... I'm using Ip device

Comment: BUT your (rather vague) question claims you need to use a "virtual port" (whatever that may be) because it "doesn't have a serial port" . Nowhere do you say WHAT you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the line you've given `socat` is listening on STDIN for input (the `-` at the start). So, you can modify your line like so to pipe the message to `socat`:

```
printf "\x02\x30\x31\x03\x38\x39" | socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1d tcp:MYServerIP:12345
```

Have a look at the manual for [`socat`](https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/socat), for fixed messages like in your example you might prefer using one of the other address types such as `socat OPEN:"/path/to/command.txt" tcp:MYServerIP:12345` or `socat SYSTEM:"printf \"command text\"" tcp:MYServerIP:12345`.

You could also use `netcat` to connect to the server in the same way if you are happy to pipe the commands in:

```
printf "\x02\x30\x31\x03\x38\x39" | nc MyServerIP:12345
```

Comment: yes , when I debug it - I can see he send me the command , so I'm starting to get to where I want. but now I need to send this data in HEX . I thought that if I add "0x.." it will translate it to HEX, but no:-) , so how can I translate it and send this as HEX and notr as ASCII ? Thanks,

Comment: Should already be in HEX: [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) uses `\xHH` to generate the HEX code 0xHH. So, if your want to send 0x550xAA you would `printf "\x55\xAA"`. You might need to add some terminating `\r\n` to your message as well.

Comment: Thank you! , now it's working. now I need to write a code that does it auto, so I will think I will create a file first and send the content of the file, so how do I do this? I have try "print test | nc myserver 1234" but i get error  - "no print mailcap rules found for type text\plain"

Comment: You've missed the "f" in "printf" (and the "5" in "12345" as well). To send a file try `cat "/path/to/file.txt" | socat `...

Comment: not working - in the test.txt I have "\x2\x30\x33\x31\x39\x3\x33\x30"  - so it send me also the "" , x , \ . can it been ignore?

Comment: You need to create the file with the HEX codes in it. Try `printf "\x020319\x0330"` > "test.txt"` first to create the file and then use `cat` to send it.

Comment: great !  - this is what I did in the end :    "printf "message in HEX with \x before any char" > test.txt  , then "socat OPEN:"/homepi/test.txt tcp:10.0.0.100:8888" . and it's working like I need. Now all I need to do is build a script that take text and converter it to HEX . If you know how to do this - show me :-) . I will try and ask here when I have a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `printf` will print text as well and can take variables and so on. I suggest you ask a new question as we've strayed away from your original one about serial ports & `socat`!